# PHP mPDF: Failed to display Yiddish Language in PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I'm using mPDF in codeigniter project. It's working well for English and Russian language but in Yiddish language it's showing only dots (.) and commas (,) like below:

[mPDF output](http://prntscr.com/lbe2z3)

While the content I'm writing in it is:

[Yiddish Content](http://prntscr.com/lbe37n)

Here is my code:

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->SetFont('avenirnext');
    $mpdf->SetTitle($title);
    $mpdf->SetAuthor('Blavatnik');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet2, 1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet3, 1);
    $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';
    $mpdf->SetHtmlHeader($header, 'OE');
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer, 'OE');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    if ($html2 != '' && $html3 != '') {
        $mpdf->SetHtmlHeader($secondHeader, 'OE');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html2);
        $mpdf->SetHtmlHeader($header, 'OE');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html3);
    }
    if ($transcriptHtml2 != '' && $transcriptHtml3 != '') {
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($transcriptHtml2);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($transcriptHtml3);
    }
    $mpdf->Output($title . '.pdf', 'I');
```

I've also tried using below solution:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8');
$mpdf->SetDirectionality('rtl');
```

What else I can change it it to make it work for all language or mainly this Yiddish language. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a font supporting hebrew characters. Furthermore, `avenirnext` is not in a standard distribution and you have not [configured an additional font](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html).

Remove the `SetFont` call and use

```
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
```

along with `lang="yi"` or `lang="he"` in a `div` or a `span` around your hebrew/yiddish text.

You can also find example code in a [autofont mPDF example file](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples/blob/development/example29_multilingual_autofont.php#L369).

Answer (score 0):

if you use `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();`

the simple solution is to add below it:

```
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true; 
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
```

That's all